# Facebook App Redirects To App Store

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-apps

Our app, still in the development stage, can post to players' walls. I don't think it matters, but if it does, we're using GoViral's showFacebookFeedDialog method for this.

We're getting some strange behavior on mobile (iOS is all we're testing right now) when trying to click the link on these posts:

1. Click wall post from Safari: URL loads fine.
2. Click wall post from Facebook app: opens the App Store.

Any idea why it's loading the app store? The link is PHP, but I tried just a plain URL (http://www.google.com) and it opens the App Store too. Obviously this is not the desired behavior, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There must be some issue with your iOS settings in the facebook app settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled Deep Linking in your app settings ? Maybe you should disable deep linking whilst your app is still under development. More info here - https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/02/21/improving-app-distribution-on-ios/

Comment: Thanks for the info, that definitely fixed the current issue. We'll have to look into deep linking more.